# How to restrict the usage of class object from common assembly?

Tags: c#, .net

I have created new public object in my class from "AssemblyName". Also, the "AssemblyName" is used for Windows application as well as in Web applications. Now i need to access the public object only when the "AssemblyName" is used in Web application. And it should not visible in "AssemblyName" when it is used in Windows application.

"AssemblyName" is the common assembly used for Web and Windows application. But the object which is created inside that assembly is accessible only when that assembly used in Web applications.

Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please talk less in “quotes” and more say specifically what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your Object as "internal" or "friend" instead of public and use the "friend assembly" feature:

[MSDN Friend assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk(v=vs.100).aspx)

In essence you can code:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System;

.....

[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("WebAssembly")]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you make that object private, access it via a public function which returns either null or the object depending on the environment?